# Imported points with coordinates were represented as one point in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, point, coordinates, import

I'm having trouble importing coordinates. I have a map over Scandinavia, and I need to import sampling coordinates that I've downloaded.

The CRS I'm using is SWEREF99 TM EPSG:3006, and the format I'm importing is in SWEREF99 TM. For one of the files I get only one point, and for the other file I get absolutely nothing, no matter what I try. One of the other files I've got has the coordinates in lon lat, which I didn't have any trouble importing.

Is there a way to easily convert the coordinates I have into decimal point of some sort? Or am I missing something?

[image: Importing the data]

[image: After importing the data]

[image: coordinates data]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110164/discussion-on-question-by-linda-trouble-importing-coordinates).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like RT90 (2.5 gon V, epsg 3021) coordinates to me, possibly with inverse X/Y. Sweref99tm usually have 6 X digits. You need to set epsg 3021 in the import dialogoue when importing the table to QGIS. Then you can reproject it to Sweref after import.

[image]